# is it possible to show an alert if a currently open record is edited or not? NetSuite

Tags: javascript, alert, netsuite, suitescript

We have a transaction, lets suppose a Sales order. We edit it by hitting EDIT button and do some changings in some fields and then we hit the SAVE button to save it.
Is it possible to know whether this transaction is edited or not (through an alert) before the record saves by hitting SAVE button on it?

i tried using newRecord/oldRecord and even load the system information. but what is required by my the client is not after record saves. its before the record saves bu the same user.

Can anyone help me? is it possible through DOM or something?

Comment: You have to store if any of the fields have been changed, and if so you can then alert the user. There are many approaches possible. For example changing a variable `var fieldsChanges = false;` to `true` on every `onChange` of any field. 
Or by adding every field to that variable like `var fieldsChange = [];`. When that array is not empty, the fieldnames in that array have been changed.
It also depends on your application, if there are any tabs, etc.

Comment: you are right. but if user changes a value of a field and then reverts it back before saving the record. will this be fetched as a change?
because it should not in my scenario.

Comment: Then you should catch that in a custom function. You could easily do that when the field is not yet in a list, store the initial value. When the current value is not the same as the initial value, you have non-saved changes. A count on the array will not suffice, but it shouldn't be that hard to create a filter, and then count.

Comment: isnt it possible through DOM? we cannot detect the change there?

Answer (score -1):

So what is the purpose of knowing if someone clicked edit but then didn't make any changes?

If they are looking to report on changes then saved search of system notes is the way to go.